# Huawei HG8145V5 Router PPPoE Password Decryption

Tags: decryption, router

My ISP is not providing pppoe accounts but I need to bridge to my server. I only have encrypted password. Password is "   $26w5`KU6gm#C73JK48OG8_jdY'dQePTOu$0'G8q\V$   " Can anyone help me decrypt, please? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that cyphertext is valid, can you confirm you copied correctly?

Comment: What type is your internet connection provided by that ISP (DSL, cable, fiber, ...)? Is it possible to sniff communication on the network from the modem to the ISB backend? PPPoE is a pretty old protocol so sniffing may be helpful to reveal the password.

Comment: I just tried sniffing. Any idea please. "
 m&y.Password=17ddd4ee53f55203f355cd41bda8e374f617e2c5213a663d486e10d17b3c9692&y.X_HW_LcpEchoReqCheck=0&y  "

Comment: That second copy was better - `mpt1234` (or maybe I copied it incorrectly.. anyway)

Comment: @Mega Tonnage The password you decrypt is correct one. Thank you

Comment: @MegaTonnage could you add an answer with how you solved it and why the first one was not good?

Comment: It wasn't a solve, I just used an existing tool - https://github.com/hu60t/hu60wap6/files/6206916/Huawei.configuration.encryption.and.decryption.tools.zip  .. it was probably me failing copy/paste the first time, they looked the same when I put them side by side afterwards. I haven't analysed that tool btw... so take a snapshot before using.

Comment: How to decrypt the encrypted password ?

Comment: thank you guys its very helpful...