# Huawei HG8245W5 Router PPPoE Password Decryption

Tags: decryption, router

My ISP is not providing pppoe accounts but I need to bridge to my server.
I only have encrypted password. Password is " $2'4e0YX=y6Q]$\9$c#-+F-h2&Tva4"GYn+qY)x>W$ "

Can anyone help me decrypt, please? Thanks

Comment: Strangely enough, you used the exact same wording as a previous question here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30930/huawei-hg8145v5-router-pppoe-password-decryption  ... how is that you have the exact same wording as another user? ... the answer in the comments for that question works, why didn't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

$2DR9-S|gZ5S/Qn}Q^MOIHl>~)/K&WE+!E%;VO@/p+\K{5MwXHSWNS!UJ!*VNGh,PoKIG!oFi]o\1j4U}N$

https://andreluis034.github.io/huawei-utility-page/#cipher

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23977)